# Embed a Firebase Console within an iFrame on a webpage

Tags: html, firebase, iframe, web, firebase-console

I'm wanting to view the Firebase Console within a webpage on my web portal, I've tried other web links within the iFrame which work but when I try putting the Firebase Console link it doesn't seem to load, can anyone do this or let me know why its not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Firebase Console</h1>
<iframe src="https://console.firebase.google.com/"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```